# android lollipop notification background colour

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

Is it possible to change the background colour of notifications in android lollipop.

I noticed that some notifications are white, some light grey and some are dark grey.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gottabemobile.com](http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/Android-Lollipop-on-the-Moto-X-2014-1.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [sftcdn.net](https://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/blog/en/2014/10/22-android-5.0-lollipop-notifications-568x506.png))</sub>

You can see the music player notification has a dark grey background. and in the second screenshot some are light grey.

How do I set this colour? And is it possible to completely change the colour e.g. any hex code. Or can you select them from a template such as material dark material light.

Thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 1):

That background is set by the material design itself, it is supposed to be white, for design matters.

[Take a look here!](https://andreagottardo.it/colored-material-design-notifications-in-android-5-lollipop/)

Or you could make a custom layout.